# Can someone show me the steps to simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$-x+x^{1.5}-2x^{1.5}+2x^{2}$

$=$

$2x^2-x^{1.5}-x$

I'm having trouble simplifying this. Can someone show me the steps?

Comment: if $a = x^{1.5}$, $-2x^{1.5} + x^{1.5} = -2a + a = -a$. The rest is just re-arranging terms around.

Comment: hint: replace $x$ with $(\sqrt{x})^2$

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the similar (the **only** similar in fact) term and then re-arrange

$$x^{1.5} - 2x^{1.5} = -x^{1.5}\\
2x^2 - x^{1.5} - x$$